# Simple design for a phpBB forum

Tags: website-design, forum, templates

I'm looking for some examples for a better design of phpBB. I would like to redesign a forum which is targeted to people with a minimal experience with forums. Now the forum isn't working well. No problems with the software itself, but the interface isn't user-friendly enough for the target audience. I feel the basic styles for phpBB aren't good for this, I want a better solution.

*Do you know any phpBB style which isn't prosilver/subsilver-based?

Are there any tutorials for a complete forum design from scratch to working code?* (phpBB preferred, but not required. If you can show me a more flexible solution, let's see.)

I don't want to start a forum design guidelines thread here, but there's a thing that I have to ask.
*Can you recommend a development workflow for a forum design?*
(My forum is on a quite small scale - think about 50-100 people, not more. Perhaps I won't have a lot of usable feedback, so I would like to use the best methods for finding the problems with the design.)

Comment: Is phpbb a requirement? Have you looked into more user-friendly forum software like Vanilla or punbb?

Comment: @Rahul No, but being able to import the actual phpBB content is a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to go with something other than phpBB, you should be able to export/import the data. For example, [there are scripts](http://www.iteisa.com/phpbb2bbpress/) to migrate from phpBB to bbPress. I would suggest you start by comparing the vanilla installations of a few pieces of forum software ([this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_forum_software) might be a starting point) and identifying which you think is most user-friendly. Next, take a look at various themes to determine any effect they might have.

You might even want to carry out some basic user-testing with your target audience - i.e. get them to register for a few forums and tell you which they find easiest to use, and why.

Personally, I find the common bbPress interface more user-friendly than phpBB. I *think* it's also easy to customise if you're a developer or have access to one.

Comment: Yeah, I've already checked out bbPress. I was satisfied with the user experience, but I would like to use a forum software with a bit bigger userbase and a plenty of support. Nice point anyway.